# Convert PSD to Android XML (layout) Format?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, file-conversion, psd

I am coding an Android App for a research project at my institution, and have been working with a designer who has rendered some attractive UI mockups in Photoshop (using CS5). I'd like to implement her designs as layouts for my Android application, and this would be WORLDS simpler if there were some way I could convert the files to XML format. I think it's rather counter-intuitive that PS offers android templates, but no real way to apply these in the android design/layout process, short of (attempting to) mimic her artwork in XML code, which I cannot do by any stretch. Is this conversion possible? Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

~Taichou

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution for this? I have a good number of PSD layouts that look great, but do me no good as I cannot convert them to anything android can use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such tool.

But you can approximate it by slicing up her mockups and using them in your GUI like you would convert a website template from an image to HTML.

As long as her layouts aren't too terribly complex you should be able to get by with flow layouts or relative layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Right click - properties - Background (in Eclipse layout design) might be what you're looking for, but remember a bitmap image won't look the same on many devices with different screen resolutions.